# How do I get the default text elements to assign/use labels?

Tags: label, ag-grid, section508

I am using ag-grid version 20.  When I put together a basic table with just the out-of-the-box text fields or number fields and I run aXe, it says that when those fields are being edited, they lack labels.

AXe suggests:
aria-label does not exist
aria-labelledby does not exist
form element does not have implicit label
form element does not have an explicit 
element has no title attribute

Upon inspection, my custom fields have the labels when they are being edited, but the default ones do not.

I've looked up information here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/ and https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-node/.  Neither the column nor the row have anything that says "set label".

I switched to ag-grid because it was supposed to be aria compliant and enabled.  I don't know if this is a bug or not, but I'd appreciate some help.  Unfortunately, their "help" is to post here, rather than send them an email.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can try filing [an issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues), but it probably won't help. There's an old vaguely matching item in the [pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/): "AG-2016 - Improve Accessibility across the grid - ARIA, ADA...". It probably is a bug, but only a small proportion of users care about accessibility, so it's always going to be a low priority. Having an ag-grid enterprise license will increase your chances of getting this fixed (they prioritise paying customers, as you would expect). Otherwise, fix it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Did that.